# SSSD alternative for pam_authz_search option in nslcd

Tags: ldap, pam, sssd

I have servers based on RHEL 7 and 8.
RHEL 7 serevers use nslcd to work with a LDAP server, RHEL 8 use SSSD.

For RHEL 7 I can provide access for users to allowed hosts only.
This functions is covered by the option in the nslcd.conf:

```
pam_authz_search        (&(objectClass=posixAccount)(uid=$uid)(|(host=$hostname.\*)(host=\\*)))
```

I use the option "**host=$hostname.\*** "  for regular users who have list of allowed servers, "**host=\\***" is used for admins who have * for the ldap host attribute.

SSSD has the option ldap_access_filter and with next sttings:

```
ldap_access_filter = (objectClass=posixAccount)
```

All users can log in to all RHEL 8 machine, what I want to avoid.

Is it possible to add host options to the ldap_access_filter as I have in the nslcd.conf on the old servers?

Thank you in advance.

UPD:

```
ldap_access_filter = (&(objectClass=posixAccount)(host=\*))
```

works for admins with * in the ldapsearch host attributes:

```
~$ ldapsearch -LLL -Q -Z uid=admin-user host
dn: uid=admin-user,ou=People,dc=my,dc=domain,dc=net
host: *
```

Also I can specify the server name directly:

```
ldap_access_filter = (&(objectClass=posixAccount)(host=servername.example.lan))
```

and it also works for users which have this server in the list:

```
~$ ldapsearch -LLL -Q -Z uid=a-testuser host
dn: uid=a-testuser,ou=People,dc=my,dc=domain,dc=net
host: servername.example.lan
```

But how can I use variables or special characters like ***** or **\***?

Comment: I think the problem is that '*' is a presence filter, i.e., it checks if there is something in the attribute 'host'.  This MS doc shows some info on escaping special characthers "https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/5392.active-directory-ldap-syntax-filters.aspx#Special_Characters"

Comment: using something like freeipa with its advanced rbac rules would make this trivial, by the way. I know, not the answer to your question, but maybe something you may be interested in using in the future for exactly this kind of things.